# If a sequence $(x_n)$ belongs to the closure of $A$ then there exist a sequence $(y_n)$ such that $|x_n-y_n|<1/n$ , for all $n$?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that if, a point $x$ belongs to the closure of $A$ then exist a sequence in $A$ that converges to $x$.
But this is true for a sequence of points?

Comment: $x_n=y_n$.{}{}{}{}{}{}

Answer (score 0):

If $x_{1} \in \overline{A}$, there is a sequence $(y_{n,1}) \subset A$ such that $y_{n,1} \to x_{1}$. If $x_{2} \in \overline{A}$, there is a sequence $(y_{n,2}) \subset A$ such that $y_{n,2} \to x_{2}$. The same idea works for every $x_{n}$.

Now, since $y_{n,1} \to x_{1}$, take $\epsilon = 1/1$ and so, there is $k_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{n,1\}> k_{1}$ implies $|y_{n,1}-x_{1}| < 1/1$. Also, since $y_{n,2} \to x_{2}$, take $\epsilon = 1/2$ and so, there is $k_{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|y_{n,2}-x_{2}| < 1/2$ for some $k_{2} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{n,2\} > k_{2}$. This works for every $x_{n}$.

Can you complete?

Comment: Obrigado Lucas! Mas, devo fazer indução ?